# Can I put my own question on hold?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question and haven't been able to properly test the answers because I think my development environment was missing something critical which I expected to be there. So I want to put my question on hold as some of the answers might have actually been correct when they didn't work for me.

Can I do something like this for when I check/update my environment?

Comment: You can delete/undelete; unless you have upvoted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can vote to close (or re-open) your own question when you have the [view close-votes Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

But that is

1. Gained at 250 reputation, so you are not there yet.
2. Not the right thing to do. Closing is for questions which have problems.

If you think your question was properly answered, but you are not yet sure enough (and won't for some time), just put a comment under your question why you are not sure yet (and if appropriate, whether and what you are doing to change that).

It would be nice if you come back to it soon, when you know, and accept the best answer answering that question then.
At that time, you might also have some more pertinent information to add (though perhaps only as a comment).

If your question is actually in trouble, it *might* be appropriate to delete it (if you don't have any upvoted answers), to remove it until you can correct all issues.
Be aware that doing so might frustrate answerers, and deleted questions still count against you.

Comment: I didn't try to _dupe hammer_ one of my own c++ questions yet, but that might be another option ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I've done it, when a commenter pointed out an existing answer Q/A pair that was quite good but unsearchable because it didn't contain the relevant keyword.  Right here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24318303/103167